# Запуск .img образа из-под usb-флешки, а не QEMU

Tags: usb, boot, live-usb

Есть образ XXX.img
Для того, чтобы запустить его на QEMU мне нужна такая команда:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -no-kvm -m 32 -boot a -fda XXX.IMG
```

Как мне залить .img образ на usb-флешку, чтобы при включении PC мой образ был запущен?
Bootloader есть в текстовом документе, что куда тыкнуть чтобы всё заработало?)

Насколько я понимаю это *floppy image*

Есть и *containing symbol information* для него.

Необходима пошаговая информация, заливал с *Win32DiskImager* , но при запуске PC и выборе USB флешки, как загрузочной, писалось, что-то вроде "AL" проходило пару секунд и итоговая надпись зависала на "ALeeee".

В общем, тут много магии, нужна ваша помощь)

Comment: Вы на реальной машине хотите с этого img загружаться?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да

Comment: Попробуйте RMPrepUSB, или его документацию...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов посмотрел в Virtual Box, в общем мой образ можно загрузить, если контроллер был выбран, как floppy,а не iso. Сейчас потестирую вашу программку, но имею мнение и вопрос, как заставить pc думать, что usb - это floppy диск?

Comment: Увы, не смогу подсказать. RMPrepUSB умеет эмулировать загрузку с полученной флешки, что в вашем случае может сохранить кучу времени.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов бесполезно

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как подсунуть ему те же параметры, что и я пишу в консольке?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов подсунул параметры, но он просто открывает в Qemu так как мне нужно, а вот с usb не хочет повторять этого